# How to generate unique (random) numbers that can be traced back to a unique source number?

Tags: random-number-generator, algorithm-design

I need to generate unique (random) numbers that I can trace back to a unique source number.

For example:

source number A can generate numbers A1, A1, A3 .... Am
source number B can generate numbers B1, B2, B3 .... Bm
...
source number N can generate numbers N1, N2, N3 .... Nm

All the source numbers A, B, .. N and generated numbers Ai, Bi, Ni should be unique and mutually exclusive.

Now for any generated number Ai, I should be able to compute unambiguously the source number A (and the same goes for Bi, Ci, ... Ni).

Can anybody help with the algorithm for this?

Use case: a user types a numeric code generated by this algorithm. The server should be able to identify this user, from the code alone. For others it should not be possible to identify the user, nor generate subsequent codes for that user.

Comment: [Yes.](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/560.pdf) $\;$

Comment: I mean can you help me with an algorithm for this?

Comment: How big should the numbers be?

Comment: Best not too big. The numbers need to be entered in a (numeric) keypad. Six digits would be ideal.

Comment: 10 digits would be easier, since then you could simply use a 32 bit block cipher like Skip32 instead of needing complicated format preserving encryption like FFX mode.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : tx for skip32 suggestion. How can I use skip32 to solve my problem? Can i use it with the solution of @fgrieu?

Comment: By definition, a random number cannot be traced back to a source number. You are not talking about generating random numbers at all, but pseudo-random numbers, and it is an important distinction.

Comment: This doesn't address the question; in principle one could select a permutation $\pi$ of (say) 128-bit strings uniformly at random, and then use $\pi(0^{96} \mathbin\| n)$ to represent a 32-bit serial number $n$ with forgery probability bounded by $1/2^{96}$ and distinguishing advantage bounded by $1/2^{64}$.  You're talking about the difference between rolling enough dice to choose $\pi$ uniformly at random _vs._ flipping 256 coins $k$ and using $\pi = \operatorname{AES}_k$.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage  I think the question contains a contradiction in terms, and I said so.  The question cannot be addressed as it stands.  If you look closely at fgrieu's response, you will see that he says "random-like", which is obviously different from what the questioner had said.  It seems clear.

Comment: @Patriot My point is that the substitution of pseudorandom generation for random variables is a standard technique in _all_ cryptography: we reason about CBC with a uniform random permutation, and instantiate it with AES; we reason about Ed25519 with a uniform random secret scalar, and instantiate it with SHA-512 of a seed.  It's technically true that there is an ontological distinction, but that's _generically_ so throughout crypto(.se), and not germane to the question at hand.  (Correction to earlier: I meant $q^2\!/2^{128}$, not $1/2^{64}$, if there are $q$ identifiers.)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage  Thank you for your attention onto this matter. Everything has now been clarified very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers $n$ (coding source) and $m$ (coding index for a given source) can be combined into a single  bitstring; e.g. with  $0\le m<2^u$ and $0\le n<2^v$, as a bitstring of $\lceil u+v\rceil$ bits. Then, converting that single bitstring into a unique random-like number can be done by encryption with a secure block cipher with block width $w\ge u+v$ bits and a fixed secret key (prefixing input with $w-\lceil u+v\rceil$ zero bits in order to reach the width $w$ of the block cipher). The random-like number will be an integer corresponding to the ciphertext bitstring, thus in range $[0\dots2^w-1]$.

Distinct pairs $(n,m)$ inputs allways lead to distinct output, because a block cipher is a permutation of its block space. Decryption (requiring the key) allows recovering the original bitstring from the random-like number, and from that $n$ and $m$. If one checks that what's deciphered could have been obtained from a valid $(n,m)$ (including $w-\lceil u+v\rceil$ zero leading bits), residual odds that a random bitstring is acceptable are $2^{u+v-w}$.

Using AES ($w=128$, regardless of key width) and $u=v=40$ ($n$ and $m$ up to about a trillion), these residual odds are $2^{-48}$. Problem is, the random-like number is up $2^{128}$ (about $39$ decimal digits). The classic [3DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) ($w=64$) or the relatively unproven [Speck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_%28cipher%29) ($w\in\{32,48,64,96,128\}$) are alternatives.

If you want a shorter unique random-like number (with as a counterpart higher residual odds that a random bitstring will be acceptable), or more choices for $w$, use [format-preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption); we have [a number of questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format-preserving) about that.

Comment: Tx for your answer!. I am new to cryptography. So you basically propose that I glue the two numbers together and then randomize them with a block cipher like AES?  What I don't understand is the sentence "(prefixing with w−⌈u+v⌉ zero bits)"?. * Is Skip32  as suggested by @CodesInChaos also useable?

Comment: a) by using above method. wat is the chance that a duplicate number will be generated for a given source number? (I need to avoid this!) b) wat is the chance that a duplicate number will be generated accross all source numbers?

Comment: @pee: The glued numbers might not be as wide as the AES input block (128-bit); so you need to add extra bits to reach 128-bit. No two distinct pairs of source number can generate a duplicate output value, if you keep the full width of the output. If $w=128$-bit of output is too much for you, you need a cipher with a narrower $w$.

Comment: Thanks guys for the excellent answers!  w+v should be no more than 32 bits. Can I use skip32 for this? How does this compare with speck? Or another algorithm that requires not much computing power and memory? I need this implemented in the firmware of a microcontroller.

Comment: @pee: I guess you wanted to write "$u+v$ should be no more than 32 bits". Yes you can use skip32. It has the advantage over speck with $w=32$ that skip32's key is stronger (80-bit vs 64-bit), and that skip32 has been around for a longer time. On the other hand speck's design and security rationale might be more modern and thoroughly justified than that of skip32 (but I've not deeply studied either). As a minor drawback of skip32, it is an even permutation, implying that if you know the mapping of $2^{32}-2$ values, then you can easily determine the mapping of the other two.

Comment: yes indeed I meant "u+v" :)